# android google maps v2 in service

Tags: android, android-service, google-maps-android-api-2, android-location

So i noticed that google maps for android has a v2. i was wondering if there is a difference between requestlocationupdate and setmylocationenabled. I want to create a service that requests user location but i know that sometimes the gps chips have issues with getting location updates so sometimes you will need to restart the phone to get them working again. Im not sure if the v2 for android maps fixes this issue or not, and if so if im creating a service to get location updates does it have to use requestlocationupdate or can it use the google map v2 version.

Answer (score 0):

[`setMyLocationEnabled()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29) enables or disables the my-location layer. This layer displays the icon on the map that will centers the camera on the map to the current location of the user and displays current bearing information.

[`requestLocationUpdates()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#requestLocationUpdates%28com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener%29) is part of the new Location API in the Google Play Services. It can be used independent of the new V2 Maps API.

Comment: so pretty much requestLocationUpdates() is the same of SetMyLocationEnabled() other than the fact that setMyLocationEnabled() automatically puts the icon on the map for you? My main question is, do they get the gps signal at the same time if i called them both or would one get them quicker than the other, because sometimes with requestLocationUpdates() i wont get a gps signal until the phone is restarted. If that is the case is there a code that can fix this issue like a hard reset on the gps chip or does the user manually have to reset their phone?